# Confused about fork function

Tags: c

This is the code I'm confused with.

```
#include "csapp.h"
void doit()
{
    if ((fork) == 0) {
            fork();
            printf("hello\n");
            return;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    doit();
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(0);
 }
```

I run this program on MAC,I got only one hello printed.I think there should be 5 lines of 'hello',because the child process return to their parent and print one 'hello' each.

Can anybody give me an answer? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you should *accept* answers that were helpful to you. :) cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call `fork()` and you just compared its address with `0`, which ls a null pointer constant.

`(fork) == 0` has too little chance to become true, so what is inside the block after the `if` statement won't be executed.

Call `fork()` to create a child process.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void doit(void)
{
    if (fork() == 0) {
        fork();
        printf("hello\n");
        return;
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    doit();
    printf("hello\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, if you have two print statements which both print hello how do you know which one is being executed ? Secondly, if you want fork executed five times you should it in some kind of loop have.

Comment: I think the example was to get 'hello' to print 5 times. Which should happen here, because parent prints once, and both children print twice.